# 'Lorem ipsum' for images

Tags: webapp-rec, images

I'm a coder and I have to test forms with images uploads. So I need some pleasant-looking dummy images, scenery or something. I'm looking for something like [lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) for images.

I found this http://dummyimage.com/ but it's not what I'm looking for.

Is there something like this?

If not, I will make one.

Comment: do you want images with certain resolution? file type (like png, jpeg etc)? or just bulk images?

Comment: what about flickr images?

Comment: Another placeholder service is [Placehold.it](http://placehold.it), but since you said DummyImage wasn't what you're looking for I assume the former isn't either?

Comment: That's a great idea. You could specify what kind of content the image should be and the size and the tool would randomly give you a landscape, a portrait, an object, etc.

Comment: Yes these should be the options a user can specify just leave blank.
Number of pics, Resolution (even in range), File type, Category (Scenery, Model, Vehicle, etc..) and what else?
Once user generates it, a series of pics will be shown. User can download some or all pics in a zip file or individually.
That'd be nice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Google - Advanced Image Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search)

> All required parameters are available
> **Search keyword input** - Scenery, Model, Vehicle etc
> Content Types
> Size
> **Exact Size**
> Aspect Ratio
> **File Types**  - Jpg, Gif, Png and Bmp
> Coloration
> **Domain** - try flickr or picassa if you want images from specific domain
> **User Rights** - you might want to choose "labeled for commercial reuse"
> Safe Search

[image]

Comment: The closest answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The [Lenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) image is a pleasant looking standard test image. It's free to use if you have to give it out as well. Or if it's just for internal testing, you could grab some from the [Flickr interesting pool](http://www.flickr.com/explore/interesting/7days/) - just make sure you don't use them in any live projects unless the licence allows it.

Comment: In American workplaces, an image of a model from Playboy Magazine might cause a problem with the Sexual Harassment Policy. Before using the image, you might want to run it by HR or your boss, with full disclosure on the source of the image, and note the historical merits of this standard test image. Contrast this to Lorem Ipsum, which is intentionally nonsensical and non-offensive.

Comment: If you get a sexual harassment issue because of using Lenna as a test image, you can bet you'll get a ton of worldwide-support from the developer community. The (cropped) Lenna pic is The standard test image.

Comment: I don't want to argue, I'm not sure that the management or HR department cares much about the history of this photo or the worldwide support of the developer community.

Answer (score 3):

Search through the [Creative Commons-licensed images uploaded to Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/search/?l=commderiv). By default it allows

> [...] for commercial use, adaptation, modification or building upon

Or just use [Yahoo! Image Search](http://images.search.yahoo.com/images/advanced?ei=UTF-8) where you can narrow down not only the license, but size and colour as well.

But no bulk download options available.

Answer (score 0):

[Dummy](http://dummy.kerns.dk/) is a newish tool that includes a library of images, plus other useful prototyping features. Check out the author's [screencast](https://vimeo.com/42252088).